# Kubernetes: Run container as non-root if there is no user specified

Tags: kubernetes

How can I make every container run as non-root in Kubernetes?

Containers that do not specify a user, as in this example, and also do not specify a SecurityContext in the corresponding deployment, should still be able to be executed in the cluster - but without running as root. What options do you have here?

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    python \
    vim
CMD ["echo", "hello world"]
```

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: hello-world
          name: hello-world
```

Comment: I think one of the few options, the only one I know of, is using an admission webhook to either reject such pods or modify them. Even that would be a bit fiddly.

Answer (score 1):

you can add Pod Security Policy to your cluster, there is an option (below) you can add to prevent any deployment from running without specifying a non-root user:

```
spec:
  runAsUser:
    rule: MustRunAsNonRoot
```

for more info about Pod Security Policy  please go to this link:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-policy/

Comment: that is not reallly covering ops question. They want to run the pod as nonRoot, not reject them if its root. Its also deprecated.